# How do I switch to another sound theme?

Tags: 11.10, customization, sound-theme

I'd like to change default sound theme to ubuntustudio-sounds, but don't understand how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Type this into a Terminal (Dash->Terminal) window:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/sound/theme_name "ubuntustudio" -t string
sudo gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/sound/theme_name "ubuntustudio" -t string
```

Then reboot, and the ubuntustudio sound theme will be on!

Comment: It sounds like from a [related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75318/cannot-install-sound-theme-in-ubuntu-11-10-gnome-shell-mode) that this method did not work for that other person.

Comment: It's different. It uses gconf instead of dconf.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember to also add ubuntu studio sound theme

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-sounds
```