# Cannot install sound theme in 11.10 

Tags: 11.10, installation, gnome, sound-theme

I found some tutorials in Google Search about installing new sound theme for Ubuntu, I made a copy sound theme (folder) into `/usr/share/sounds`. It was easy to copy with commands but I cannot choose new sound theme in *System Settings* → *Sound*. I've used `gconf-editor` to enter new sound theme manually in *desktop* → *gnome* → *sound*, with No success.

What's the problem with this way? Anyone who succeeded in changing into a new sound theme on Ubuntu  11.10, please let me know.

Comment: It does not look like it's possible to me to change anything other than the alert sound through the Sound menu in 11.10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/65545/how-do-i-switch-to-another-sound-theme

Comment: Where do you copy the sound profile? From another Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 1):

By using the dconf-editor, you can change the sound theme.

If you had not installed the dconf-editor, you can install it by the following command in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Type the following in terminal.

```
dconf-editor
```

And, Set  ***theme name***  in "org> gnome> desktop> sound> theme-name"

***theme name*** is sound theme directory name. (/usr/share/sounds/***theme name*** )